# Even though I initialize my array as [length*2][length/2+1][3] it seems to be [length*2][4][????]

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

This is clearly a C newbie error but I can't get it. This program should write the data that was previously saved in each arr[][] position but it only shows 4 out of seven (if largo = 6) and instead of deleting the old data (ej : "1/2) it smashes it together like "1/22/1"

Additional data: if I initialize "valoresPosiblesFinal[largo*2-1][(largo/2)+1][3]" with a four at the end (I thought the termination character was the problem) it stops right there

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dosDados(){
    int largo; //max length of the dice. it's used to calculate the length of the arrays
    int min = 2; //minor value posible
    char auxRes[4]; //I don't even use it anymore

    printf("Ingrese el largo de los dados: ");
    scanf("%d",&largo);

    char valoresPosiblesFinal[largo*2-1][(largo/2)+1][3];//array where the sets n/n are stored
    int auxArr[largo+2]; //array to know how many elements are there in each set (ie: if I saved 1/2 I don't want to overflow it with 2/1)

    for(int i = 0; i < largo-1; i++){
        auxArr[i] = 0;
    } //inialice the array auxArr to avoid erratic behavior

    for(int i = 1; i <= largo; i++){  //loop to emulate the firt dice
        for(int j = 1; j <= largo; j++){  //loop to emulate the second dice
            if((i+j >= min) && (i+j<=largo+largo)){ //Used to know if i+j is within the posible values 
                sprintf(valoresPosiblesFinal[i+j][auxArr[i+j]],"%d/%d",i,j);  //I declare that the value of valoresPosiblesFinal is "%d/%d"
                
                auxArr[i+j]++; 
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < largo*2-1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< largo/2+1;j++){
            printf("[ %s ]",valoresPosiblesFinal[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    dosDados();
}
```

Comment: C has no bounds checking. It's your job as the programmer to make sure the code doesn't go out of bounds.

Comment: The innermost array dimension `[3]` can only hold a string with 2 characters plus terminator. It can (un)happily overflow because the output from `"%d/%d"` is always too much to fit.

Comment: Unrelated: If the comments in your code are important, please translate them into English. Otherwise, please remove them.

Comment: @user:7582247 Those are only for me to remind me what the hell I did an hour ago ​ But you are right, I've just translated it

Comment: @Julian.gxnzalez I see :-) Then please remove them from the question.